# SQL Query: Showing previous years date based upon date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a query that looks at a date column (dateofcall) from table named (callstable) and creates 2 additional columns with the yyyy-mm format of the 2 previous years. 
In addition to this the query needs to look at the date in dateofcall column and only show results from the previous month. 
To put that in english if I ran the query today (7/10/2015) the result would look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using *SQL Server 2012*, you can take advantage of the `FORMAT()` function.

You can use both `FORMAT()` and `DATEADD()` to get your result:

```
Select  DateOfCall,
        Format(DateAdd(Year, -2, DateOfCall), 'yyyy-MM')    [2 Years Ago],
        Format(DateAdd(Year, -1, DateOfCall), 'yyyy-MM')    [1 Year Ago]
From    CallsTable
Where   DatePart(Month, DateOfCall) = DatePart(Month, DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate())
And     DatePart(Year, DateOfCall) = DatePart(Year, DateAdd(Month, -1, GetDate())
```

Comment: Except you really shouldn't use format when you can just use convert, please see http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution that would work on any tsql version:

```
select cd,convert(char(7),cd1,126) oneyear,
convert(char(7),cd2,126) twoyears from 
(select dateofcall cd, dateadd(year,-1,dateofcall) cd1,
dateadd(year,-2,dateofcall) cd2, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) cu1 from callstable) cs
where month(cd)=month(cu1) and year(cd)=year(cu1)
```

see here for a [working example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/372471/query-showing-dates-of-previous-years).